# how to show multiple message at a time in amazon lex

Tags: amazon-lex

hi I am working on amazon lex and

1. want to know that how can I break the line in amazon lex to show text in the next line. I have used \n but it is not working. see screenshots.

[image]

2. And can I show 2 messages to user at a same time?. i am new on lex so please guide me. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Amazon lex doesn't support for the new line.
- You can handle in the front end, like keeping **@newLine** in response which reflected as next line if you are using web interface.
- You need to write the custom code in the front end for updating the response in new line.
- In the below code I used and identifier @newLine to insert the response as two different messages.
- Write the below code in Ajax call response or SDK call response.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){

         //Add the botResponse in the Amazon lex.
         let botResponse = "This is a first response @newLine This is second response @newLine This is third response."
           
           let pushToChat = botResponse.split("@newLine")
         
           $("#btn2").click(function(){
             pushToChat.forEach(res =>{
            $("ol").append(`<li>${res}</li>`);
           })
           });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
      <ol>
         <li>List item 1</li>
         <li>List item 2</li>
         <li>List item 3</li>
      </ol>
      <button id="btn2">Append list items</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

- Hope above code will helps you.

Comment: Edited the above answer. Hope it will help you

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224329/discussion-between-tayyab-and-paradigm

Comment: can you join this chat if you can help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718778/provide-slot-value-for-specific-slot-in-response-and-resume-the-conversation?noredirect=1#comment114490340_64718778